# D'DNS as Default Gateway

Tags: gateway, ddns

I need a help! I have router A on 1st location and I have router B on 2nd location - they are miles away !! Can I set DDNS domain name of router A -"server" as default gateway for router B? YES or NO. How to do it; if you can't put DDNS as letters into field of "default gateway"? Don't ask me why; I just need that-okay THANK YOU !!﻿

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO.

It's not possible for two different reasons:

- The gateway on a routing table entry must be an IP address not a domain name.
- The gateway on a routing table entry must be on a directly attached interface. There cannot be any routers between you and your gateway.